GoogleSignIn().signIn() causes IPhone app to crash
Steps to reproduce
Call the GoogleSignIn().signIn() function
Expected results
Open popup so I can log in like on Android (It works completely fine on Android, it was working fine on iPhone aswell on the start, but at some point it stopped working)
Logs:
flutter: tried to googlesign in
Lost connection to device.
Error: Unable to terminate com.x.x on C1EA8AEA-F758-4BCD-9A9B-A4929205B2EE:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 3:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
Simulator device failed to terminate com.x.x.
found nothing to terminate
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
The request to terminate "com.x.x" failed. found nothing to terminate
found nothing to terminate
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl terminate C1EA8AEA-F758-4BCD-9A9B-A4929205B2EE com.x.x
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.

Code sample:
  Future<void> signInWithGoogle(context) async {
try {
  print("tried to googlesign in");
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
  print("passed it!");
  if (googleUser == null) return;

  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
      await googleUser.authentication;
  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );
  await _signInWithCredential(credential);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (builder) {
      return Container(
        child: Text(e.toString()),
      );
    },
  );
}

}

I faced this today, you have to follow these instructions to modify your Info.plist in XCode accordingly: https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_ios#ios-integration

Thank you, in my case at some point after pulling files from git my info.plist contained 2 CFBundleURLTypes - one that plugin required and one that just appeared. I had to delete the second one where CFBundleTypeRole was set to Editor.
